# Water-damage computer

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, hardware-failure, water-damage

My child poured some water in my computer. The computer did not blow up or anything like that, it just lost connection with monitor. I shuted it down. I opened it, cleaned it without taking apart and dried some water I saw around. 
I managed to start the computer for once but soon the windows screen broke into little squares like the graphics is breaking down or something. then it fell into blue screen and shut down.

Now it has problem to start. Whenever I start it, it runs for few seconds and then restarts itself, runs for few seconds and restarts itself and it restarts like this forever.
When its starting, all the fans are running and the motherboard lights are up.

I took the components apart. I took the graphics out first to try if it would start without it, but it did the same thing. Now I guess some components are dead or faulty, but I dont know which. My best guess is motherboard, RAM and/or graphics, because I found some water on them or around them. But could it also be CPU? though it did not blow up and no water got close to CPU?

How can I determine which components are dead, which to replace?

Comment: Take it to a qualified repair technician.

Comment: Your biggest mistake was not taking it immediately to a specialist. Powering it back up means you now have no way to tell if dry components were damaged by shorting on the wet components. Take it to a repairer now & see if anything at all can be salvaged.